# Pushing data in an array with foreach in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

In order to fill a multiselect dropdown, I would like to request my web service, get data from it, and then create a custom array with specific objects, different from those I got from the WS.

I would like to be able to do it in ngOnInit in order to have this multiselect dropdown already filled when the page is loaded.

My only problem is Angular doesn't seems to want to let me push things in an array with a forEach inside ngOnInit. It doesn't give any error, but just doesn't fill my array.

Here is some code :

```
fonctions: any[];
dropdownList = [];

ngOnInit() {

this.serviceFct.getAll()
.subscribe(response =>  {
    this.fonctions = response as any;

    this.fonctions.forEach(element => {
    this.dropdownList.push({item_id: element.idFct, item_text: element.nomFct });
    }); 
});}
```

However, if i try to fill the same array with the same foreach with a button, it just works like a charm. Why and how to fix it ?

Edit :
Answers there gave me the idea to try something that did work :

```
let dropdown = [];
this.fonctions.forEach(element => {
  dropdown.push({item_id: element.idFct, item_text: element.nomFct });
}); 
this.dropdownList = dropdown;
```

Why did this work and not my first implementation ?

Comment: You should use .pipe() and .map() to get the response back however you want it then use the async pipe.That would be the pro solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **"pro"** way to do it.

```
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    .
    .
    .
    ngOnInit():void {
      this.serviceFct.getAll().pipe(
        map(res=> {
          return res.map(element=>({item_id: element['idFct'], item_text: element['nomFct'] }))
          })).subscribe(data => {
          this.dropdownList = data;
      });
    }
```

If you do this, don't forget to unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy()`. Every time you use subscribe you must `unsubscribe` unless you using the `async` pipe which does it for you.

To learn more about [susbcriptions](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)

The **"more pro"** way to do it

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    .
    .
    .
$dropdownList: Observable<[]>;
...
    ngOnInit():void {
      this.$dropdownList = this.serviceFct.getAll().pipe(
        map(res=> {
          return res.map(element=>({item_id: element['idFct'], item_text: element['nomFct'] 
        }))
     }))'
   }
```

**IN YOUR HTML**

```
<YOUR DROP DOWN ELEMENT>
  <BLAH *ngFor="let element of $dropdownList | async"></BLAH>
</YOUR DROP DOWN ELEMENT>
```

**Extra Tips:**

- The async pipe subscribes and unsubscribes for you
- specify void or the return type of your funcions (is good practice)
- Try to avoid using **any** and create an model (interface or class)
- Create a function with all this logic and call it in the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: I was about to ask you for an exemple when you told me to use pipe and maps on my above post. Thanks A LOT for this, i now understand what you mean and how to  use them ! I was definitely using the "easy" way without taking advantage of the power of Angular !

Comment: @Ishiru I'm glad I was able to help. After learning angular, RxJS is the second things to learn in my opinion then NgRx.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dropdown out of scope this  `let dropdown = this.dropdownList;`

```
ngOnInit() {

this.serviceFct.getAll()
.subscribe(response =>  {
    this.fonctions = response as any;
    let dropdown = this.dropdownList;

    this.fonctions.forEach(element => {
    dropdown.push({item_id: element.idFct, item_text: element.nomFct });
    }); 
});
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't my array only exist in ngOnInit scope by doing this ? I need it to exist in global scope because my multiselect dropdown component rely on its datas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceFct.getAll()
        .subscribe(response =>  {
            this.fonctions = response as any;

            this.fonctions.forEach(element => {
                this.dropdownList.push({item_id: element.idFct, item_text: element.nomFct });
            });
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work either. I found a way to make it work (you can check the "edit" on my first post), thus i have no idea why it does work and my first attempt didn't. I guess it was scope related but as far as I know it should have worked :/.